# Visual Studio Code error "libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory gcc"

Tags: c

I am trying to use postgresql with c code. However, when i compile i get an error `libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory gcc` even though I have included the path of postgresql as mentioned in the code. I was not able to find anything so far on internet to solve this issue for VS Code. Please help.

I just kept the code simple to 'hello world' in order to focus the error and not confuse everyone with more C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

int main()
{

// prints hello world
printf("Hello World K");

return 0;
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\15\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: If you get that error message during compilation, then you must add the include path for your compiler. Add  a line `"-I <path-to-includ-folder>",` to the `"args": [  .... ]` array in `tasks.json` file. Your change to `c_cpp_properties.json` only tells Intellisense where to find it and avoids squiggly lines in the editor